# Vue Router not working when deployed on heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, vue-router

i'll just deploy my LaraVue app on Heroku, everything is fine but the router is not working. when i visit `https://example.com/read` its display error 404 ngix. the app work properly in localhost but error when i deploy it

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any','.*');
```

resources/js/routes/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../pages/Home.vue";
import Read from "../pages/Read.vue";

const routes = [
    { path: "/", component: Home },
    { path: "/read", component: Read },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Do you have Vue and PHP in the same repo? Otherwise you could deploy your front-end app to Heroku/Vercel.

Comment: Yes i do store the the front end code on laravel directory called resources/js